# Interval Schedule Variation - Subset of books to read in order to maximize enjoyment

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, intervals

I have been trying to solve this design problem for quite a while but getting stuck in several assumptions.
The problem is stated as :

You are an avid reader of fiction, but you only read one fiction book at a time. For a given book *i*,
you can accurately predict the amount of enjoyment ei you will receive from reading the book, and
how much time it will take you to read that book ri. The time starts at 0. You also know that at
time ti there will be a movie coming out based on book i. If you don't finish reading book i by the
time ti, your enjoyment for that book drops to negative infinity, since you won't be able to avoid spoilers and
that would annoy you to no end. Given a collection of n books described by parameters ei; ri; ti, your
goal is to come up with a plan - which subset of books to read and when - in order to maximize
the total enjoyment. Assume that the books are already sorted by non-decreasing times of movie
releases, i.e., t1 <= t2 <= .. <= tn. Also, assume that all input numbers are positive integers. Design a
dynamic programming algorithm for this problem that runs in time O(n max ti).

What I tried : 

i. I tried to calculate finish times fi = ti - ri and applying earliest finish times on the intervals. 

 ii. Calculated weight(entertainment) / fi ratios, sorted in non-descending orders and took the best. 

 iii. Sorted ti is given, so according to ti and entertainment of particular book i, adding them to solution set. 
So far, I haven't came across any optimal solution. 

 I have figured this out to be a weighted interval scheduling problem but confused on how can i sort the given intervals to come up with optimal solution.

Comment: This problem is weakly hard (generalizes knapsack, basically), so sorting and doing something greedy-ish is very unlikely to get you anywhere.

Comment: so according to you what approach @DavidEisenstat is best suitable here?

Comment: Dynamic programming. You can infer from the running time that the DP states probably should have a time component.

Answer (score 0):

Let `f(t, i)` represent the maximum enjoyment achievable, considering the first `i` books, where the last book chosen is completed at time `t`. Fill in the blanks:

```
f(t, 0) ->
  <fill>;

f(t, i) when (t > ti) ->
  <fill>;
  
f(t, i) ->
  max(
    % Read book i
    ei + f(t - <fill>, i - <fill>),
    % Don't read book i
    f(<fill>, i - <fill>)
  ).
```

Note that "where the last book chosen is completed at time `t`," doesn't mean the `i`th book will have been read last, just that we've considered up to the `i`th book.